# how to validate size of pathvariable that is string type to be exact value in spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot

How I can validate size of path variable to be exact size? Variable is string type.
`@GetMapping("getLegal/{legalCode}")`
`public ResponseEntity getLegalFrom(`
`@PathVariable @Size(min = 9,max = 9) String legalCode) {`
`return sharedService.getLegal(legalCode);`
`}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use **@PathVariable** annotation with Regular Expressions. To do that Change your **@GetMapping** to

```
@GetMapping("getLegal/{legalCode:[a-zA-Z0-9]{9,9}}}")
```

Comment: it gives 404 not found with no exception or error message how do I handle or find what kind of exception it gives